# node build adding x86_64 and failing on M1 chip?

Tags: node.js, maven, apple-m1

I am trying to build an application but it fails when setting up the node.

```
    > Task :my-app:nodeSetup FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my-app:nodeSetup'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':my-app:detachedConfiguration22'.
   > Could not find node-16.4.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz (org.nodejs:node:16.4.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.4.0/node-v16.4.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz
```

it looks like its adding x86_64 to the end of the artifact? and because of that its not finding it in the repository. Any ideas? Please let em know if you need more info.

Comment: For an M1 you have to arm based and not x86... maybe node-v16.4.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz ???

Comment: @khmarbaise yes I think that is the issue but how do I change it?